# How do I show graphical ticks in Victory?

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

It's simple to get tick *values* to display in Victory, but how do I get actual line segments to show up?  Do I have to create a TickComponent from scratch?  This seems like a mainline scenario so I feel like I'm missing something.

Current code example:

```
      <VictoryAxis
        tickCount={4}
        tickFormat={e => DateFns.format(e, tickDateFormat)}
        domain={[
          DateFns.subDays(firstDate, paddingX),
          DateFns.addDays(lastDate, paddingX),
        ]}
      />
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you're seeing? And maybe the rest of the chart code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a style for the ticks:

```
<VictoryAxis
  ...
  style={{
    ticks: {stroke: "grey", size: 5},
  }}
  ...
/>
```

You can play with it live [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis/#style).